# VBA convert ddmmyyyy text to date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

There seems to be lots of similar questions but nothing that quite seems to answer this one.

I have created the below sub to convert a column of text to dates. It works in some scenarios, i.e. where the date has 8 characters such as 10022017, but not if the value has 7 characters such as 1022017.

Any ideas appreciated.

```
Sub convertDate()

    'Find the last Row with data in a Column

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnSelect).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

    'convert column from string to date

    For i = RowSelect To lastRow
        Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value = Format(Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value, "00/00/0000")
    Next i


End Sub
```

Hi again all,  still having a few problems, the ideal formula seems to be =DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"00-00-0000"))  if for example A1 = e.g. 02022017. Still haven't found the best way to do this with VBA as everything seems to run up against the truncated zeros problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your format is going to be consistent then try this.

This adds a `0` before `Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value` when there are 7 characters.

```
For i = RowSelect To lastRow
    Select Case Len(Trim(Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value))
    Case 8
        Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value = Format(Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value, "00/00/0000")
    Case 7
        Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value = Format("0" & _
        Cells(i, ColumnSelect).Value, "00/00/0000")
    End Select
Next i
```

But be careful with numbers like `1122017`... this can be `11/2/2017` or `1/12/2017`

**Edit**

Looking at `10022017`, I realised that `1122017` will be `1/12/2017` and not `11/2/2017` as your `mm` zeros are not getting truncated.

OP wants a formula as well

`=IF(LEN(A1)=8,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&MID(A1,3,2)&"/"&‌​RIGHT(A1,4)),"dd/mm/‌​yyyy"),TEXT(DATEVALU‌​E(LEFT(A1,1)&"/"&MID‌​(A1,2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A‌​1,4)),"dd/mm/yyyy"))`

Comment: Thanks, that was the kind of path I was thinking of, just couldn't quite piece it together.

The other thought I had was trying to implement the workbook function datevalue(text(whatever cell value,"00-00-0000")

Comment: Like this `=IF(LEN(A1)=8,TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&MID(A1,3,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4)),"dd/mm/yyyy"),TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,1)&"/"&MID(A1,2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4)),"dd/mm/yyyy"))`

Comment: or directly: `=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),2),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6))` and set the cell formatting to "dd/mm/yyyy" ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel: Yup that is another way to do it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I prefer `DATE` over `DATEVALUE` because of the system settings may see it as `mm/dd/yyyy` ;)